# Trouble populating combobox from sql table

Tags: vb6

Need some minor help. I'm having an issue was as my combobox won't populate with the table I'm referencing too. Here's my code:

```
Public Function GetCodeDesc(sCode As String) As String
    Dim strSQL As String, strAnswer As String
    Dim objGetInfo As New ADODB.Recordset

    strSQL = "SET ANSI_NULLS OFF"
    Set objGetInfo = New ADODB.Recordset
    objGetInfo.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM SH_RAWOCODES WHERE CODEX='" & sCode   & "'       ORDER BY CODEX"
    Set objGetInfo = New ADODB.Recordset
    objGetInfo.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

    If Not objGetInfo.EOF And Not objGetInfo.BOF Then
        strAnswer = objGetInfo.Fields(28)
    End If

    strSQL = "SET ANSI_NULLS ON"
    Set objGetInfo = New ADODB.Recordset
    objGetInfo.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

    GetCodeDesc = strAnswer
End Function
```

---

Can anyone tell me where I might've went wrong?

Comment: It would help to know what the issue is. It looks like your issue is getting results back from your query, and nothing to do with getting it into a combobox.

Comment: ok the issue is that I need the combobox  to display the contents of the table provided and for some reason I'm missing something where it will not disply the contents of the table I have assigned to show.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any code that adds items to a combobox so I am guessing that you don't have that. I also don't see in your sample where you expect to have more than 1 record returned so I am going to offer a generic put things into a combobox routine.

```
If objGetInfo.EOF = False And objGetInfo.BOF = False Then
    objGetInfo.MoveFirst 'redundant, but just to be sure we're on the first record
    Combobox1.Clear 'clear any current items
    Do While objGetInfo.EOF = False
        Combobox1.AddItem objGetInfo.Fields("MyField").Value
        objGetInfo.MoveNext 'move to the next record
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thanks jac well appreciated!!